# How to handel Combo Box which loaded From sql also Then this Combox recieve the value From Get Data Button

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I have on Vendor combobox I make it refill it's data From the SQL database using the data source 
but Suppose when I select the Update Button the Vendor Value Display on The Vendor Combo Box also I did it 
the Problem is

after an update and send the data to the SQL database by the Update Button on the next Time of this process Give me an error on the Vendor Combo Box that is An unhandled exception of type `'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll`

```
private void FillVendorBox()
        {
            var result = db.VendorTBs.Select(v => v);
            comboBoxVendor.DataSource = result;
            comboBoxVendor.DisplayMember = "VendorName";
            comboBoxVendor.ValueMember = "VendorCode";
            comboBoxVendor.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
   ProductsTB Product = null;
        private void btnData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ProductCode = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxProduct.SelectedValue);
             Product = (from b in db.ProductsTBs
                           where b.ProductCode == ProductCode
                           select b).First();
  comboBoxVendor.SelectedValue = Product.VendorCode;
}
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
Product.VendorCode = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxVendor.SelectedValue);
db.SubmitChanges();
btnCancel_Click(sender, e);
}
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { if (comboBoxVendor.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                FillVendorBox();
            }
            else
            {
                comboBoxVendor.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
}
```

This Error Message:
    private void btnData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    comboBoxVendor.SelectedValue = Product.VendorCode;
    }

This Error Message:

```
ArgumentNullException was unhandled 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
Be Note that error appears on the second Time of Test Code

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is generating from linq query

please change .First() to .FirstOrDefault() so if no record exist system will return null
which you can verify before assigning value

comboBoxVendor.SelectedValue = Product.VendorCode;

Comment: I tried it ,but Unfortunately same Error , Did i Need to make Code After Update or if Null  . I think the Problem is The Combo still have the Last value selected but i don't know How to let the combo refresh the data as I tried to Call FillVendorBox() but also doesn't help

Comment: please provide me your stack trace so I can tell exact source of issue.

Comment: @Megh- > at StockMang.exe!StockMang.UpdateProduct.btnData_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 54 C#    . This message appear from Exception method : value cannot be Null .parameter name:key

Answer (score 0):

Check the DataBase as 
VendorCode on the ProductTB on some product was have Null Value on the DataBase , That's why it was return Null.